# Creating div dynamically with htmlhelpers inside?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with my MVC app which is shown in the pictures.

So when i click on the one of the checkboxes, script will be set the visible of the `div` to `visible`. But this is not good idea because the second `div` have a empty space above.

[image: First div with <code>htmlhelpers</code>]
[image: empty space which i dont want]

Checkboxes with script insdie:

```
    <label><input type="checkbox" onclick="biurowyScript();" id="biurowyCheck" />  Pracownik biurowy</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" onclick="przewodnikScript();" id="przewodnikCheck" style="margin-left: 30px" />   Przewodnik</label>
```

biurowy div

```
   <div id="biurowy" style="visibility: hidden">
            <div class="form-group">

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy.Nazwa_uzytkownika, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy.Nazwa_uzytkownika, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

przewodnik div:

```
 <div id="przewodnik" style="visibility: hidden">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Przewodnik.Uprawnienia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Przewodnik.Uprawnienia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Przewodnik.Uprawnienia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In scripts i only set visible of the divs  to `visible`. But like i said this is not the good idea for this app. So what i can use to fix this ?

Comment: When you use visibility the page still creates the space for the element, if you use the display property it will not create the space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **display="none"** instead of **visibility="hidden"**

```
<div id="biurowy" style="display: none">
            <div class="form-group">

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy.Nazwa_uzytkownika, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy.Nazwa_uzytkownika, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT:

When you use visibilt=hidden it keeps the space, while using display=none you it does not keep the space. You can show it with jquery the same way, i mean `$(item).show()`